# What loop invariants to use for an integer logarithm?

Tags: c, frama-c, formal-verification, loop-invariant, proof-of-correctness

As I am having my first steps in C formal verification with Frama-C, I am trying to formally verify an integer binary logarithm function written as follows:

```
//@ logic integer pow2(integer n) = (n == 0)? 1 : 2 * pow2(n - 1);

/*@
    requires n > 0;
    assigns \nothing;
    ensures pow2(\result) <= \old(n) < pow2(\result + 1);
 */
unsigned int log2(size_t n)
{
    unsigned int res = 0;
    while (n > 1) {
        n /= 2;
        ++res;
    }
    return res;
}
```

I am using Frama-C 20.0 (Calcium), with the command `frama-c-gui -rte -wp file.c` (I do not have the Jessie plugin for some reason). I have checked the post-condition to hold for up to n = 100,000,000 (using standard-library asserts), but this function fails to verify formally despite my best efforts, and Frama-C tutorials typically involve trivial loop variants that decrement (instead of halving) every iteration, thus not that close to what I am trying to do.

I have tried the following code annotations, some of which are likely unnecessary:

```
//@ logic integer pow2(integer n) = (n == 0)? 1 : 2 * pow2(n - 1);

/*@
    requires n > 0;
    assigns \nothing;
    ensures pow2(\result) <= \old(n) < pow2(\result + 1);
 */
unsigned int log2(size_t n)
{
    unsigned int res = 0;
    /*@
        loop invariant 0 < n <= \at(n, Pre);
        loop invariant \at(n, Pre) < n * pow2(res + 1);
        loop invariant pow2(res) <= \at(n, Pre);
        loop invariant res > 0 ==> 2 * n <= \at(n, Pre);
        loop invariant n > 1 ==> pow2(res + 1) <= \at(n, Pre);
        loop invariant res <= pow2(res);
        loop assigns n, res;
        loop variant n;
     */
    while (n > 1) {
    L:
        n /= 2;
        //@ assert 2 * n <= \at(n, L);
        ++res;
        //@ assert res == \at(res, L) + 1;
    }
    //@ assert n == 1;
    return res;
}
```

The annotations that fail to verify are loop invariants 2 and 5 (both Alt-Ergo 2.3.0 and Z3 4.8.7 timeout). As far as invariant 2 is concerned, the difficulty appears to be linked to integer division, but I am not sure what to add to make WP able to prove it. As for invariant 5, WP can prove that it’s established, but not that it’s preserved. It may require a property able to capture what happens when n becomes 1, but I am not sure what could work.

How may I specify the missing information to verify these loop invariants, and is there another Frama-C analysis that could allow me to find loop invariants more easily?

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: Why `size_t n`?

Comment: You're not giving your definition of ACSL `pow2` function. It is not impossible that some failed Proof Obligations are related to it instead of to the rest of your specifications. For a meaningful answer, please provide a complete specification (by the way, if you're going to use `size_t`, don't forget to `#include <stddef.h>` as well).

Comment: @jarmod I intend to use this function on array indices. Simple as that.

Comment: @Virgile I did define pow2 in the first code block. I copied it in the second one for clarification. As for stddef.h, it didn’t make a difference. In my experience, stdlib.h was always enough; maybe it in turn includes stddef.h.

Comment: @PierreColin sorry about that. I shouldn't read SO as a diversion from endless meetings 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general remark, it is often a good idea to name your annotations, especially when you start having several loop invariants for the same loop. It will allow you to more quickly pinpoint the ones that are failing (see below for an example, although you're free to disagree with the names I have chosen).

Now back to your issues: the main point is that your invariant 2 is a bit too weak. In case `n` in the current loop is odd, you can't establish that the inequality holds at next step. With a tighter bound, namely `\at(n,Pre) < (n+1) * pow2(res)`, the hypothesis at the start of the current step is strong enough to prove that the invariant holds at the end of the step, provided we know that `res` will not overflow (otherwise `1+res` will eventually become `0`, and the inequality won't hold anymore).

For that, I've use an intermediate ghost function to prove that `n < pow2(n)` for
any `unsigned`, which allows me, thanks to the `pow2_lower` invariant below, to ensure that `res_bound` is preserved by any loop step.

Finally, a minor remark on `pow2`: it doesn't matter here, since arguments are `unsigned`, hence non-negative, but in the general case, an `integer` argument can be negative, hence you might want to make the definition more robust by returning `1` whenever `n<=0`.

All in all, the following program is entirely proved with Frama-C 20 and Alt-Ergo (`frama-c -wp -wp-rte file.c`). There are still two assertions that seem to be needed to guide Alt-Ergo in its proof search.

```c
#include "stddef.h"

/*@ logic integer pow2(integer n) = n<=0?1:2*pow2(n-1); */

/*@ ghost
/@ assigns \nothing;
   ensures n < pow2(n);
@/
void lemma_pow2_bound(unsigned n) {
  if (n == 0) return;
  lemma_pow2_bound(n-1);
  return;
}
*/

/*@
    requires n > 0;
    assigns \nothing;
    ensures pow2(\result) <= \old(n) < pow2(\result + 1);
 */
unsigned int log2(size_t n)
{
    unsigned int res = 0;
    /*@
        loop invariant n_bound: 0 < n <= \at(n, Pre);
        loop invariant pow2_upper: \at(n, Pre) < (n+1) * pow2(res);
        loop invariant pow2_lower: n*pow2(res) <= \at(n, Pre);
        loop invariant res_bound: 0 <= res < \at(n,Pre);
        loop assigns n, res;
        loop variant n;
     */
    while (n > 1) {
    L:
        /*@ assert n % 2 == 0 || n % 2 == 1; */
        n /= 2;
        /*@ assert 2*n <= \at(n,L); */
        res++;
        /*@ ghost lemma_pow2_bound(res); */
    }
    //@ assert n == 1;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I did find this lower-bound invariant by myself last night, but the upper-bound one is a lot more subtle and really changed a lot. I managed to lighten it a bit from your code by ditching the lemma function and rewriting it as a loop invariant, and removing all assertions except the one on ```n % 2```. The label may be removed as well. Anyway, thank you for this solution!